# problemas con Ngclass en dropdown

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular9, dropdown

Estoy usando Angular CLI: 9.0.7, quiero     hacer un menú dropdown donde cada item cambie el color de fondo cada vez que el cursor está sobre de él, sin embargo se confunde entre los item y cambiar de color un item que no es el indicado:

Estoy usando Angular CLI: 9.0.7

[image: Dropdown issue]

Estoy usando ngClass y creando un evento mouseover
**Html code**

```
<div class="dropdown">
<mat-icon svgIcon="arrowback" role="button" id="dpm" class="margindropmessage" style="margin-top: -18px;margin-left: -20px; width: 80%; height: 80%;" data-toggle="dropdown"></mat-icon>
<div class="dropdown-menu dropmessage" aria-labelledby="dpm">
    <div class="dropdown-1st-item" [ngClass]="firtsDropItemMessage" (mouseover)="changeStyle($event)" (mouseout)="changeStyle($event)">
        <label class="firtitem">Responder</label>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-item dropitemmessage" [ngClass]="dropItemMessage" (mouseover)="changeStyle1($event)" (mouseout)="changeStyle1($event)">
        <label class="my-1 titleitem">Reenviar mensaje</label>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-item dropitemmessage1" [ngClass]="dropItemMessage1" (mouseover)="changeStyle2($event)" (mouseout)="changeStyle2($event)">
        <label class="my-1 titleitem">Destacar mensaje</label>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-item dropitemmessage2" [ngClass]="dropItemMessage2" (mouseover)="changeStyle3($event)" (mouseout)="changeStyle3($event)">
        <label class="my-1 titleitem">Eliminar mensaje</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

traté usando una variable para cada item
**Ts code**

```
  firtsDropItemMessage:string = 'fstitemdroppmessage';
  dropItemMessage:string = 'dropitemmessage';
  dropItemMessage1:string = 'dropitemmessage1';
  dropItemMessage2:string = 'dropitemmessage2';

  changeStyle($event){
    this.firtsDropItemMessage = $event.type == 'mouseover' ? 'fstitemdroppmessagehover' : 'fstitemdroppmessage';
  }

  changeStyle1($event){
    this.dropItemMessage = $event.type == 'mouseover' ? 'dropitemmessage' : 'dropitemmessagehover';
  } 
  changeStyle2($event){
    this.dropItemMessage1 = $event.type == 'mouseover' ? 'dropitemmessage1' : 'dropitemmessagehover2';
  }
  changeStyle3($event){
    this.dropItemMessage2 = $event.type == 'mouseover' ? 'dropitemmessage2' : 'dropitemmessagehover2';
  }
```

**Css code**

también cree cada clase para cada item por ejemplo:

```
.dropitemmessage {
    color: #545871;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.dropitemmessagehover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #58BBFF;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

Comment: Hola. Por favor traduce tu respuesta al español. Estas en stackOverflow en español.

Comment: Esto se puede arreglar con una directiva.

Comment: asi mismo como tienes tus clases de .css usa el `:hover` de `css`, Ejemplo: dropitemmessage:hover{...} y seria todo, aca una pequeña [guia](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)